# How to get selected combobox value and load its corresponding data in html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, combobox

I have combobox that loads the value from data base. I want when user select value from the combobox the form should load the corresponding values from database into html form.
Here is code I am trying:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="c" > 
    <form id="aa" action=""   method="post"  >
        <br><br><br>

        <select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style=" width:150px;" onChange="this.form.submit();">
            <?php 
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "valet";

                // Create connection
                $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if (!$conn) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                $arr = array();

                $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_user  ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";
            ?>
            <option value="">-select user-</option>
            <?php           
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $arr[] = $row;
                    }

                    foreach($arr as $key => $row){
                        echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["id"]."</option>";
                        $GLOBALS['a'] = $row["first_name"];
                        $GLOBALS['b'] = $row["last_name"];
                        $GLOBALS['c'] = $row["phone"];
                        $GLOBALS['d'] =  $row["company_id"];
                        $GLOBALS['e'] = $row["register_on"];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                    header('Location: webservices.php');
                }

                mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
        </select>

        <br><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php $GLOBALS['a']  ?>" name="first_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="First Name*">
        <br><br><br><br>

        <input type="text" id="last_name" value="<?php $GLOBALS['b']  ?>" name="last_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Last Name*">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="phone" value="<?php $GLOBALS['c']  ?>" name="phone" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Phone*">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="company_id" value="<?php $GLOBALS['d']  ?>" name="company_id" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Company ID*">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="register_on" value="<?php $GLOBALS['e']  ?>" name="register_on" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Register On*">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <button name="edituser" id="edituser" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;" >
            <img src="images/save.png" alt="">
        </button>
        <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
            <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
        </button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Please help me how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: without reloading page you can use Javascript (like jquery) functions. Reloading page you need to check $_POST vars (the form var are stored here on the same page, you redirect here)

Comment: i dont want to load the page on combobox selection ..please provide me srcipt  for getting selected value and retrieving the corresponding recode from database and then placing them on html form

Comment: well, you then can try with javascript =)

Comment: If the data set isn't too large, you can pre-select all the needed data, and output that along with the id's for manipulation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do this. For the record `Marco Mura` did give you the solution to the problem. You just didn't want to research the problem and solve it after the solution was given to you.

```
$("#id").change(function(){
    $.post("www.example.com?val=" + $(this).val(),function(response){
        $("#mydiv").html(response);
    })
})
```